# Confused about linear independence of two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I put the two vectors 1,0,0 and 0,1,0 next to each other

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

I can see that they are independent since I cannot write $(1,0,0)^t$ as $(0,1,0)^t$.

But I've heard that "If you have a row of $0$'s in your matrix, it's linearly dependent"

But the matrix above has a row of zeroes but is still linearly independent. Which means I'm understanding something wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement (“If you have a row of $0$'s in your matrix, it's linearly dependent”) holds if you have $n$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$. That is not the case here: you have **two** vectors in $\Bbb R^{\bf 3}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing two notions.

The vectors $(1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,1,0)$ are linearly independent, since the *columns* in the matrix are independent.

The *rows* in the matrix may be linearly dependent, since they represent combinations of $(1,0),(0,1)$ and $(0,0)$, which are clearly dependent...

Answer (score 0):

The correct statement is probably this one: If you have $n$ column vectors in the $n$-dimensional space, so that when put one next to each other there is a row of $0$'s in your matrix, then it's linearly dependent.

There are several ways to see why this is true. Let $A$ be the square matrix formed. First it is very easy to show that

"If $A$ has a column of zero's then the vectors are linearly dependent"

This is indeed easy: the condition implies that one of your vector is the zero vector.

To go back to the original statement, we use:

(1) The vectors are linearly dependent if and only if $\det A = 0$, and

(2) $\det A = \det A^t$.

Then if $A$ has a row of zero, then $A^t$ has a row of zeros. Then the vectors formed by the columns of $A^t$ is linearly dependent. Then $\det A^t =0$ by (1). By (2) $\det A = 0$, then the column of vectors formed by $A$ is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at row vectors: [0,0] must be a linear combination of [1,0] and [0,1].

Because the number of vectors is larger than the number of variables in each vector.

But if you look at columns it's the opposite relationship.

Too few columns in relation to elements in each column.